# How to left-justify lines of code to the left edge of the window in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, format, lines-of-code

I have alot of code that has white space to the left of the lines of code in my eclipse project.
I would like to select pieces of this code and remove the extra white spacing so each line lines up with the left edge of the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the code you wish, and press SHIFT+TAB until the code lines up to the edge of the screen.
You could also go to:

```
Window->Preferences->general->Editors->Text Editors
```

and when you're there, specify the tab width under:

```
Displayed Tab Width.
```

You can also customize Eclipses' formatter:

Go to:

```
Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter
```

Select the formatter and press Edit. Edit it to your desire.

Then select the text you wish to format and press Ctrl+Shift+F

Comment: I knew it was something simple. Thanks!